# Why does my deg in CSS linear-gradient() not work properly?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a background for my body by experimenting with the linear-gradient(). However, it seems like there is a problem with the deg. After a while of failing to make it on my own, I went to a website which could help make a linear-gradient with a degree but when I copied the code, it looks completely different. Included are the code I copied, the website, what the preview is and what the result for me ended up being.
The website used: https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Code:

```css
body {
  background: #4c4c4c;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #4c4c4c 0%, #595959 12%, #474747 22%, #474747 22%, #666666 25%, #2c2c2c 50%, #000000 51%, #111111 60%, #2b2b2b 76%, #4c4c4c 83%, #4c4c4c 83%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #4c4c4c 0%, #595959 12%, #474747 22%, #474747 22%, #666666 25%, #2c2c2c 50%, #000000 51%, #111111 60%, #2b2b2b 76%, #4c4c4c 83%, #4c4c4c 83%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #4c4c4c 0%, #595959 12%, #474747 22%, #474747 22%, #666666 25%, #2c2c2c 50%, #000000 51%, #111111 60%, #2b2b2b 76%, #4c4c4c 83%, #4c4c4c 83%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

[image: Preview]

[image: My result]

Comment: Works fine if you give the body a height - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LYyBoWd

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't add height & width and it repeats the gradient on top of each other.

```css
body {
  background: #4c4c4c;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #4c4c4c 0%, #595959 12%, #474747 22%, #474747 22%, #666666 25%, #2c2c2c 50%, #000000 51%, #111111 60%, #2b2b2b 76%, #4c4c4c 83%, #4c4c4c 83%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #4c4c4c 0%, #595959 12%, #474747 22%, #474747 22%, #666666 25%, #2c2c2c 50%, #000000 51%, #111111 60%, #2b2b2b 76%, #4c4c4c 83%, #4c4c4c 83%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #4c4c4c 0%, #595959 12%, #474747 22%, #474747 22%, #666666 25%, #2c2c2c 50%, #000000 51%, #111111 60%, #2b2b2b 76%, #4c4c4c 83%, #4c4c4c 83%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```